# How to disable annoying build error notification when using project generated from pnp spfx generator

Tags: visual-studio-code, yeoman, sharepoint-online, yeoman-generator, spfx

I have created a project using the pnp/spfx Yeoman generator (https://github.com/pnp/generator-spfx), and now I get a Build Failed" notification that pops up in the lower right-hand corner of my VS Code window along with a beep every time I save a file and there are errors anywhere.

I would like to turn this off somehow.  I have looked everywhere and I have not been able to figure out what is triggering this notification, or how I could go about turning it off.

I was hoping someone on here that has experience using this generator and could point me in the right direction.

This is what the notification looks like:

[image: Build Failed Notification]

As you can see there is no way to click on the notification to configure to turn it off or anything.  No Right click options either.

Comment: This might have something to do with the gulp serve task running I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same annoying issue. You can turn off the toast in the `gulpfile.js`. Add the following:

```js
build.mergeConfig({
  showToast: false
});
```